# What's the flying saucer image on the Skeptics.SE error page?

Tags: discussion, design

Through [this meta question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3895/when-you-first-visit-skeptics-se-there-is-a-cover-picture-with-a-flying-saucer) I discovered that there's a funny picture of a mock flying saucer crash scene on this [site's error page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/error):

[image]

I'm guessing the Stack Exchange design budget doesn't stretch as far as setting up a photoshoot like this... so what's the story behind this photo? Is it a stock photo, scene from a film, etc?

I did a google image search but it just found crackpot/conspiracy sites that used the colour original of this image for illustration.

Comment: Paging @skilivvz - he [suggested it](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/404-error-and-captcha-images-suggestions-welcome/3392#3392). I believe it was always the area51.se error image. Maybe SE's budget *did* stretch that far!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know the story of how it was chosen for Skeptics.SE, but the scene is from a couple's over-the-top Halloween decorations.

The "[Halloween Lawn](http://blog.syracuse.com/strangecny/2007/10/alien_crashes_in_north_syracus.html)" is in North Syracuse, New York, and is frequently decorated for Halloween by the couple Suzi Campanaro and Stan Munro. In 2007, [they made a UFO crash scene](http://blog.syracuse.com/strangecny/2007/10/alien_crashes_in_north_syracus.html).

The photograph is uncredited, which is upsetting to me.

Comment: Brilliant. I love the attention to detail, like the "fog machine [that] leaks smoke from the flying saucer's cracked dome every 20 seconds or so"!

Comment: Hm, it does seem that the photo should be credited.

Comment: That same house on [google street view](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/107+Sandra+Dr,+Syracuse,+NY+13212,+USA/@43.1137494,-76.1537276,3a,75y,245.74h,79.86t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1selTtuM9jvRFt1It4WMDqWg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x54a6ab39ec830940!8m2!3d43.1136183!4d-76.1539605!6m1!1e1)